# Android list applications that can view an unknown file

Tags: java, android, file, list

Hi I'm working on an app where I need to list all types of applications able to open a file. If the file were an image I would do something like this normally to show all applications capable of viewing the image.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "image/*");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

However say I have an unknown file how could I list all applications able to view a file so the user can select the appropriate application to open the file in my application.

I also need the titles listed in an arraylist if possible so I can list them in a listview.

Thank you for any help with getting a list of applications capable of viewing a file

===================================

**Edit**

Alright well something easier how can i get the applications from the above intent into an arraylist i could just do image/* audio/* etc and add them all to a list and then list them in a listview and that would solve my problem

Comment: How are you determining if the application can handle the file? If you are not writing all of these apps yourself, they have to be able to filter for the intent that you are creating for the unknown file. How will those apps know what intent to filter for when you call startActivity(intentWithUnknownFile);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay well i figured my problem out what i was looking for was

```
    Intent audioIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    audioIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(Opener.file), "audio/*");
    List<ResolveInfo> audio = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(audioIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo info : audio){
        String label = info.loadLabel(packageManager).toString();
        Drawable icon = info.loadIcon(packageManager);
        String packageName = info.activityInfo.packageName;
        String name = info.activityInfo.name;
        iconlabel.add(a.new HolderObject(label, icon, audioIntent, "audio/*", packageName, name));
    }
```

But the main thing in the code above is the queryIntentActivities method that was what solved my issue allowing me to add those apps to a list

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no API in android that links files to a program like in windows. Your best choose I'm afraid is to build a database of known file types and program/android app linked to them.

Comment: what i'm basing this off of is root explorer when you click an unknown file an "opener" appears and there is three tabs the third tab lists applications like mail, browser, text viewer etc all things that would be able to open the unknown file basically trying to copy that

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to list the application that are capable of opening a particular file.

```
// extension  : The file extension (.pdf, .docx)

String extension = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension.toLowerCase());

        if (null == mimeType) {
            // Need to set the mimetype for files whose mimetype is not understood by android MimeTypeMap.
            mimeType = "";
        }
        File file = new File(filePath);
        Uri data = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(data, mimeType);
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"));
```